# ¿Se puede poner como id el valor de una variable PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Mi problema es el sigiente:
A mi botón le asigno un id que contiene el valor de una consulta PHP.
Aqui el código:

```
<input type="text" name="Articulo" id="Articulo"  value="1"/>

<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" 
      value="1"/>

<!-- aqui el boton le asigno como id un valor de PHP-->
<!-- este valor lo obtengo de la base de datos -->

<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>" 
      class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart" >Añadir al carrito
</button>
```

El problema es cómo  obtener el valor de ese id y llamarlo en javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //***
    function validarInput() {
        //no sé cómo obtener ese valor del id y colocarlo
        document.getElementById('aquí el problema').disabled = !document.getElementById("quanti").value.length;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al botón le puedes asignar un evento `onclick` que llame a la función y pasarle la palabra reservada `this` que hace referencia al botón en sí. Una vez recuperado el botón al que le has dado click, podrás obtener su id.

Además, de esta manera, tampoco necesitarás recuperar el id del botón ya que mediante la palabra reservada `this` puedes deshabilitar el botón directamente ya que hace referencia al elemento al que acabas de hacer click.

Ejemplo:

```js
function hazClick(boton){
  console.log(boton.id);
  boton.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="idBoton" onclick="hazClick(this)">Haz click</button>
```

Comment: en mi vida he ocupado la el console del navegador, estoy en la perdición

Comment: @Hermann El console del navegador simplemente es una manera de mostrar aquí el resultado del ejemplo. Sin embargo, tu podrías almacenar `boton.id` en una variable o utilizarlo donde quisieras, no hay que utilizarlo necesariamente con `console.log` (que es una herramienta de depuración).

Comment: @Hermann De todas maneras, tal y como muestro en mi respuesta, como haces referencia al botón al pasarle como parámetro la palabra reservada `this`, no te haría falta volver a buscar ese valor mediante `document.getElmentById` si no que ya lo tienes almacenado en la variable `boton`.

Comment: Esta es una excelente respuesta, quizá la mejor solución para el problema que planteas. En cuanto al `console.log` se suele usar mucho en las respuestas, simplemente para mostrar que el código funciona, en vez de usar el desagradable `alert`. Saludos.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero ya casi lo resuelvo, solo que no entendi bien lo que dijiste: - "no te haría falta volver a buscar ese valor mediante document.getElmentById si no que ya lo tienes almacenado en la variable boton"   . Y ENTONCES COMO MANDO EL VALOR? PARA MANDARLO A MI FUNCIÓN validarInput()

Comment: @Hermann Fíjate que yo a la función la llamo desde el botón mediante el siguiente código `onclick="hazClick(this)"`. La palabra `this` es una palabra reservada en Javascript y hace referencia al elemento con el que estés interactuando. En el otro lado (al recuperar el parámetro desde la función) lo he llamado `boton` para que estuviera más claro. Es decir, `boton` equivale al resultado de hacer `document.getElementById('idBoton')`, ya que tanto la palabra `this` como el método para recuperar ese botón referencian al mismo botón.

Answer (score 0):

Pruebalo asi y avisame si te sale un alert con el id de la variable que viene desde el php

```
<input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" value="<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>">

<input type="button" name="boton01" id="boton01" value="Sacar el valor del input text">

<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#boton01").click(function () 
        {
             alert($("#variable").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alli deberia de funcionarte con la variable que viene desde el php si tu conexión anda bien, me avisas cualquiera cosa

Saludos